# Error when starting eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04 lts (through virtualbox)

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I start Eclipse through the terminal (~/eclipse/eclipse) I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Eclipse opens anyway and seems to work fine, but this error keeps bothering me.

Comment: I am not sure this is completely relevant, but searching for `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String` lead me to find this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122

Comment: That bug does look like it is the problem - in which case it is fixed in Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)